# C code Calculations not outputting correctly after adding exit for program

Tags: c

Hey guys n gals first time poster first time learning code.

I am sure I am missing something very small that comes naturally when you stare at code long enough. Why are my calculations not working? what am I missing ?

I can get it working without implelemting the # exit but im sure im missing something here.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
char input;
int a,b,c;

while(1)        {
    
    
    printf("\nPlease Enter Temperature in kelvin \n\nThen enter # when you have had enough:\n ");
    scanf(" %c", &input);
    if(input == '#'){
    break;
    }
    
    if(input != '#')                        {



    scanf("%d",&c);
    printf("\n1.Convert to celcius\n2.Convert to fahrenheit\nEnter choice now\n");
    scanf("%d",&a); 


    

    switch(a)           {
    case 1:
    b=(c-273);
    printf("Temperature in celcius is %d\n\n",b);
    break;
    case 2:
    b=((c*9)/5)-460;
    printf("Temperature in fahrenheit is %d\n\n",b);
    break;
    default:
    printf("You selected wrong choice");
    break;                                                              /// End of code here
                        }

                                            }

    getchar ();

                                              
                
                }
    return 0;
                
}
```

Comment: Do you really format your code that way on purpose?

Comment: Not sure what you mean?.Did I mean to use that specific style to do my calculations? I am new its all I know.If you have a better suggestion I am all ears and ready to learn.

Comment: regarding; `        if(input != '#')
        {`  This can be completely removed

Comment: regarding; `scanf("%d",&c);`  what do you expect the user to do when the program 'hangs', waiting for an input and the user has no idea what they are expected to input?

Comment: regarding; `"\nPlease Enter Temperature in kelvin"
            "\n\nThen enter # when you have had enough:\n ");
        scanf(" %c", &input);`   the prompt says to enter a 'temperature in kelvin' However, the call to `scanf()` will only input a single character

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding; 1) please consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces..   2) Not every editor is set to move the cursor 8 spaces when a <tab> is encountered.  Strongly suggest replacing each <tab> with 4 spaces (and eliminate the extra spaces.

Comment: OT: regarding: `scanf(" %c", &input);`  always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to determine if the operation was successful.  Note: the `scanf()` family of functions returns the number of successful 'input conversion specifiers' (or EOF)

Comment: suggest, before: `scanf("%d",&c);`  to insert the statement: `ungetc( c, stdin )` so the full kevin value will be input

Answer (score 1):

the following proposed code:

1. appropriately horizontal spaced
2. appropriately vertically spaced
3. includes the suggested changes from the comments to the question
4. displays how to cleanly display menu
5. displays how to honor the right margin (column 72 or 80)
6. replaces 'magic' numbers with meaningful names

and now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define CONVERT_KEVIN_TO_CELCIUS 273
#define OFFSET_KEVIN_TO_FAREN 460


int main( void )
{
    char input;
    int a,b,c;

    while(1)        
    {
        printf("%s",
            "\nPlease Enter Temperature in kelvin"
            "\n\nThen enter # when you have had enough:\n");
        scanf(" %c", &input);
        
        if(input == '#')
        {
            break;
        }
        
        ungetc( c, stdin );
        scanf("%d",&c);
        printf("%s",
            "\n1.Convert to celcius"
            "\n2.Convert to fahrenheit"
            "\nEnter choice now\n");
        scanf("%d",&a); 

        switch(a)           
        {
            case 1:
                b=(c-CONVERT_KEVIN_TO_CELCIUS);
                printf("Temperature in celcius is %d\n\n",b);
            break;
            
            case 2:
                b=((c*9)/5)-OFFSET_KEVIN_TO_FAREN;
                printf("Temperature in fahrenheit is %d\n\n",b);
            break;
            
            default:
                printf("You selected wrong choice");
            break;
        }
    }

    getchar ();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Why are my calculations not working?

Code has various technical problem [well addressed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64289776/2410359) elsewhere.

Thought I'd mention some numeric issues.

To [convert K to °F](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fahrenheit#Definition_and_conversion):

```
°C = 0K − 273.15
°F = °C×9/5 + 32
```

To do so with integer math and get the best answer

```
//  (K     − 273.15)×9/5      + 32
//  (K*100 − 27315)×9/(5*100) + 32
// ((K*100 − 27315)×9         + 32×500)/500
// ((K*100 − 27315)×18        + 32×1000)/1000
// above using real math, below using integer C math
// t = (K*100 − 27315)×18 + 32×1000; (t + signof(t)*500)/1000
// More simplifications possible

int t = (K*100 - 27315) * 18 + 32*1000;
t += (t < 0) ? -500 : 500;  // round by adding half the divisor, correctly signed
F = t/1000;
```

To do so with FP math and get a good integer answer

```
#include <math.h>
F = lround((K − 273.15)*9.0/5.0 + 32);
```